# Cart observer unit testing

Tags: magento2, event-observer, unit-tests

I created a module that has some logic to modify the price of certain items depending on a few conditions pertaining to the other items in the cart.

I'm trying to write a unit test to test that the price of the items will be modified as expected.

I'm struggling to figure out how do I pass different cart contents to my test, since my class only gets instantiated as an observer on the add_to_cart event.

I might be missing something obvious, but I've looked around and cannot seem to see how this should be done.

Comment: I'm also trying to figure this out....

Comment: I figured it out already

Comment: Can you please share your solution?

Comment: @sv3n it boils down to understanding the differences between unit testing, integration testing and functional testing. In unit testing using mocks will do the trick.